# How to take snapshots of existing crypto holders for providing 1:1 airdrop

Tags: binance, cryptocurrency, airdrop, bep20

I am developing a new BEP-20 token which will replace an abandoned project. I want to give all current holders of the old token equal amount of the new token. My requirements are two

1. How to take snapshot of all the existing holders
2. How to airdrop them equal amount of new token.

Thanks in anticipation